# Hierarchical Table and Max Level

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, common-table-expression, hierarchical

I am using following function in sql to get levels of my nodes but currently my nodes become more than 20000 ,So running this function takes 50 sec ,how can I optimize it ?

```
   WITH cteLevels
AS
(
SELECT
  TopicId
  ,ParentId

  ,1        AS [Level]
FROM   Accounting.Topics
WHERE parentId = 0 


UNION ALL

SELECT
  Accounting.Topics.topicId
  ,Accounting.Topics.Parentid
   ,[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
 FROM   Accounting.Topics

       INNER JOIN cteLevels
         ON ( Accounting.Topics.ParentId = cteLevels.TopicID ) 

)

-- Viewing Data
SELECT
  *
FROM   cteLevels
```

Comment: For such queries number of nodes/rows is less important. From my point of view, which is much important  for recursive queries is number of levels. What is the maximum number of levels in your case ? Why do you use `SELECT * FROM cteLevels` and you don't have a filter `SELECT * FROM cteLevels WHERE Topic = @param` (for example) ?

Comment: I know to get max level should change to :
Select Max(Level) from ctelevels
but the problem is the performance this algorithm is too lazy !! it takes 50 sec.

Comment: I would add a filter (`WHERE` clause). for `SELECT * FROM cteLevels WHERE ...`. You should add the indexes created on `Accounting.Topics` to this question. What is the actual execution plan ? NB: an algorithm can't be lazzy, can be optimal, suboptimal, etc.